# ML Kit object detection using custom model how to get bounding box coordinate?

Tags: android, kotlin, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

Custom object detection model: mobile_object_labeler_v1

outputs:

| Name | Type | Description | Shape | Min/Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| probability | Feature <uint8> | Probabilities of the outputs classes. | [1,631] | [0]/[1] |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KKCV.png)

there is only each class probabilities and no bounding box coordinate in outputs, so how to get the coordinate? Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.